# Does wearing a disguise affect armor rating

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

In ESO you can pick up different disguises and some of them look really nice. You wear them as a separate piece, so I wonder if they affect your armor rating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disguises and costumes (as well as the upcoming guild tabbards) are all cosmetics only (i.e. they don't have any influence on your stats), with slightly different behavior:

- **Tabbards** are permanent (till you unequip them) and help you showing your membership in a guild (will be introduced with version 1.3 some time soon).
- **Disguises** allow you to make some hostile NPCs neutral towards you and they might allow you to use passages otherwise locked, e.g. to sneak into bandit camps and similar. Whenever you receive any damage, they're removed (and the equipped item is destroyed).
- **Costumes** work similar to disguises, but they won't disappear if you're hit, meaning that you're able to keep them equipped while in combat.

Note that the naming ingame isn't very consistent. Most quest disguises will disappear once you're hit in combat, while some of those are permanent (e.g. the disguise obtained on *Stros M'Kai*).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using medium armor in the game, but all the pieces have different styles, which makes my character look all messy. I made a lot of in-game pictures, and I have a costume that looks quite nice. So until I can make my own set of armor, I'd like to have my costume equipped, but like to have the benefits of my medium armor.

Comment: All your armor effects (stat changes as well as set bonuses) are always active, even if you can't see the armor (either due to a costume or due to the helmet being hidden).

Answer (score 1):

No. Disguise items' only gameplay effect, aside from the obvious change to your appearance, is the pseudo-stealth effect they grant in certain areas during quests. No disguise provides any stat bonuses.